# C++11 template: How to ensure that the type inherits a class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

In Java generic, when I want to ensure that the type of some generic class must inherit a class, I can code as below:

```
public class MyHandler<T extends Serializable> {}
```

This means that `T` must extend/implement the class/interface `Serializable`, otherwise, the compiler will generate an error.

How to get the same thing in C++11? I mean, if I code C++11 as below:

```
template<typename T>
class MyHandler {}
```

In this piece of code, `T` can be any class. But, if I want to tell the class users that `T` must inherit the class `boost::archive::text_oarchive` (just like `<T extends Serializable>` in Java), what can I do?

Comment: Do you want to prevent instantiating objects from your class at compile-time or run-time?

Comment: @asmmo Usually the point of this is to prevent failed instantiations due to an incompatible type argument from producing incomprehensible errors. As such, and since templates are a compile-time thing anyway, preventing it at run-time makes no sense whatsoever -- you cannot instantiate a template at run-time.

Comment: @cdhowie I know that but I would prefer `std::enable_if` to the posted answer, hence I asked that question. or Have I missed a thing?

Comment: @asmmo Both `std::enable_if` and the technique in the posted answer are 100% compile-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) for checking.

```
template<typename T>
class MyHandler {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<boost::archive::text_oarchive, T>::value, "T must inherit boost::archive::text_oarchive");
};
```

---

Since C++20 we can use [constraint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), e.g.

```
template<typename T> requires std::is_base_of_v<boost::archive::text_oarchive, T>
class MyHandler {};
```

Comment: Does it make more sense to use `std::is_convertible`?  `is_base_of` is perfectly happy with private and protected inheritance, which I'm guessing (based on the Java comparison) wouldn't meet OP's needs.

Comment: @StephenNewell `std::is_convertible` seems allowing too much; anyway we can add much conditions for adjustment based on OP's intent.

Comment: `static_assert`? hmm, I don't want to use this if we have some other ways.

Comment: @Yves what's wrong with `static_assert`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo  If I `#define NDEBUG`, will `static_assert` be ignored?

Comment: @Yves No, it will not.

Comment: @TedLyngmo  OK, I thought it was just like `assert`.

Comment: @Yves Ok, no, [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) is a great help for making error messages clearer when making templates.

Comment: @TedLyngmo   alright, then `static_assert` is OK for me.